# Bootstrap JQuery - Modal scrolling doesn't work after child modal opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Hi all the help I can find online doesn't seem to solve my problem.

I have 2 modals.
A Parent and a Child. The parent modal has a button when upon click, opens a child modal and closes the parent modal.

Here's my code:

```
$("#parentModal.close").click(); //Closes Parent

$('#childModal').modal('toggle'); //Opens Child
$('#childModal').modal('show'); //Opens Child
```

However, on the child modal, scrolling is disabled.

I came across the following answers to resolve my issue but none of them seems to work:

- `$('.modal').css('overflow-y', 'auto');`
- `$('body').addClass('modal-open');`

Any advice?

Comment: Can you make a working example which reproduce the issue?